# understanding aarch64 assembly function call, how stack is operated?

Tags: assembly, callstack, arm64, abi

test.c (bare metal)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add1(int a, int b)
{
int c;
c = a + b;
return c;
}

int main()
{
int x, y, z;
x = 3;
y = 4;
z = add1(x,y);
printf("z = %d\n", z);
}
```

I do `aarch64-none-elf-gcc test.c -specs=rdimon.specs` and get a.out. I do `aarch64-none-elf-objdump -d a.out` and got the assemlby code. Here is the main function.

```
00000000004002e0 <add1>:
  4002e0:   d10083ff    sub sp, sp, #0x20       <-- reduce sp by 0x20 (just above it are saved fp and lr of main)
  4002e4:   b9000fe0    str w0, [sp, #12]       <-- save first param x at sp + 12
  4002e8:   b9000be1    str w1, [sp, #8]        <-- save second param y at sp + 8
  4002ec:   b9400fe1    ldr w1, [sp, #12]       <-- load w1 with x
  4002f0:   b9400be0    ldr w0, [sp, #8]        <-- load w0 with y
  4002f4:   0b000020    add w0, w1, w0          <-- w0 = w1 + w0
  4002f8:   b9001fe0    str w0, [sp, #28]       <-- store x0 to sp+28
  4002fc:   b9401fe0    ldr w0, [sp, #28]       <-- load w0 with the result (seems redundant)
  400300:   910083ff    add sp, sp, #0x20       <-- increment sp by 0x20
  400304:   d65f03c0    ret
0000000000400308 <main>:
  400308:   a9be7bfd    stp x29, x30, [sp, #-32]!   <-- save x29(fp) and x30(lr) at sp - 0x20
  40030c:   910003fd    mov x29, sp                 <-- set fp to new sp, the base of stack growth(down)
  400310:   52800060    mov w0, #0x3                    // #3
  400314:   b9001fe0    str w0, [sp, #28]           <-- x is assigned in sp + #28
  400318:   52800080    mov w0, #0x4                    // #4
  40031c:   b9001be0    str w0, [sp, #24]           <-- y is assiged in sp + #24
  400320:   b9401be1    ldr w1, [sp, #24]            <-- load func param for y
  400324:   b9401fe0    ldr w0, [sp, #28]           <-- load func param for x
  400328:   97ffffee    bl  4002e0 <add1>           <-- call add1 (args are in w0, w1)
  40032c:   b90017e0    str w0, [sp, #20]           <-- store x0(result z) to sp+20
  400330:   b94017e1    ldr w1, [sp, #20]           <-- load w1 with the result (why? seems redundant. it's already in w0)
  400334:   d0000060    adrp    x0, 40e000 <__sfp_handle_exceptions+0x28>
  400338:   91028000    add x0, x0, #0xa0  <-- looks like loading param x0 for printf
  40033c:   940000e7    bl  4006d8 <printf>
  400340:   52800000    mov w0, #0x0                    // #0 <-- for main's return value..
  400344:   a8c27bfd    ldp x29, x30, [sp], #32  <-- recover x29 and x30 (look's like values in x29, x30 was used in the fuction who called main)
  400348:   d65f03c0    ret
  40034c:   d503201f    nop
```

I added my understanding with `<--` mark. Could someone see the code and give me some corrections? Any small comment will be appreciated. (please see from `<main>`)

ADD : Thanks for the comments. I think I forget to ask my real questions. At the start of main, the program who called main should have put it's return address(after main) in x30. And since main should call another function itself, it should modify x30, so it saves x30 in its stack. But why does it store it in sp - #0x20? and why are the variables x,y,z stored in sp + #20, sp + #24, sp + #28? If the main function calls printf, I guess sp and x29 will be decremented by some amount. Is this amount dependent on how much stack area the called function(here printf) uses? or is it constant? and how is the x29, x30 storage location in main determined? Is it determined so that those two values are located just above the called function(printf)'s stack area? Sorry for too many questions.

Comment: _"why? seems redundant. it's already in w0"_ You're looking at unoptimized assembly. Such code is likely to contain lots of redudant instructions.

Comment: Yes.  It is generally a good idea to compile with at least `-O1` to avoid strange stack movements.

Comment: In fact if you enable optimizations you will probably get which hardly uses the stack at all.  `add1` should be just two instructions long: `add w0, w0, w1 ; ret`.

Comment: Your analysis looks generally correct.  Note that loading `w1` with `z` is not redundant, since that's where it needs to be in order to be passed to `printf`.  However `mov w1, w0` would have done it more simply; or if the code were optimized, `z` could have been computed in `w1` in the first place.  But was there a more specific question that you wanted to ask?

Comment: When not optimizing, the compiler generates code as if the "true home" of every variable is in memory, and so every reference to that variable should read or write memory accordingly.  It doesn't pay attention to the fact that some other register (or even the *same* register!) may already contain a copy of the value.  So as you see, the result will tend to be very inefficient and redundant, and it's not a good model for how you should write your own assembly code.

Comment: @NateEldredge  I see, w0 seems to be the "x = %d\n" string for the printf. I don't know how exactly the %d is filled but it's not a question here.

Comment: `x0` not `w0` for the address of the string, but yes.  "Filling in" the `%d` is what `printf` does, it parses the format string and the `%d` tells it to take the number in `w1`, convert to decimal, and output it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In laying out the stack for `main`, the compiler has to satisfy the following constraints:

- `x29` and `x30` need to be saved on the stack.  They occupy 8 bytes each.
- The local variables `x,y,z` need stack space, 4 bytes each.  (If you were optimizing, you'd see them kept in registers instead, or optimized completely out of existence.)  That brings us to a total of `8+8+4+4+4=28` bytes.
- The stack pointer `sp` must always be kept aligned to 16 bytes; this is an architectural and ABI constraint (the OS can choose to relax this requirement but normally doesn't).  So we can't just subtract 28 from `sp`; we must round up to the next multiple of 16, which is 32.

So that's where the 32 or `0x20` that you mention comes from.  Note that it is entirely for stack memory used by `main` itself.  It's not a universal constant;  you would see it change if you added or removed enough local variables from `main`.

It has nothing to do with whatever `printf` needs.  If `printf` needs stack space for its own local variables, then the code within `printf` will have to take care of adjusting the stack pointer accordingly.  The compiler when compiling `main` does not know how much space that would be, and does not care.

Now the compiler needs to organize these five objects `x29, x30, x, y, z` within the 32 bytes of stack space that it will create for itself.  The choice of what to put where could be almost completely arbitrary, except for the following point.

The function's prologue needs to both subtract 32 from the stack pointer, and store the registers `x29, x30` somewhere within the allocated space.  This can all be done in a single instruction with the pre-indexed store-pair instruction `stp x29, x30, [sp, #-32]!`.  It subtracts `32` from `sp`, then stores `x29` and `x30` in the 16 bytes starting at the address where `sp` now points.  So in order to use this instruction, we have to accept placing `x29` and `x30` at the bottom of the allocated space, at offsets `[sp+0]` and `[sp+8]` relative to the *new* value of `sp`.  Putting them anywhere else would require extra instructions and be less efficient.

(Actually, because this is the most convenient way to do it, the [ABI](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ihi0055/latest/) actually requires that stack frames be set up this way, with `x29, x30` contiguous on the stack in that order, when they are used at all (5.2.3).)

We still have 16 bytes starting at `[sp+16]` to play with, in which `x,y,z` must be placed.  The compiler has chosen to put them at addresses `[sp+28], [sp+24], [sp+20]` respectively.  The 4 bytes at `[sp+16]` remain unused, but remember, we had to waste 4 bytes somewhere in order to achieve the proper stack alignment.  The choice of arranging these objects, and which slot to leave unused, was completely arbitrary and any other arrangement would have worked just as well.

Comment: Re: un-optimized code: [Why does clang produce inefficient asm with -O0 (for this simple floating point sum)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53366394) explains why compilers behave this way at the default `-O0`

Comment: Thank you so much. That explained many things. I think the most confusing part for me was stp x29, x30, [sp, #-32]. I thought sp is preserved by this instruction when it's not. I wasn't aware (maybe forgot..) about the pre-index and post-index.

Comment: @ChanKim: You're welcome.  Don't forget about the `!` in the `stp` instruction - that's what requests the pre-indexing.  I wish they had chosen a better syntax.

Comment: For those not familiar with arm load/store addressing  :  https://developer.arm.com/documentation/102374/0101/Loads-and-stores---addressing